# How to get query parameters value from deep link while dynamic link created using AppInvitation class using Firebase?

Tags: firebase, xamarin.android, firebase-dynamic-links

In my app, I am sending invitation to people to join my app. I am using AppInvitation IntentBuilder Class to create Intent. After these steps, one URL-link gets generated that we can send to invitees.

I have written below code to generated that link and start the activity to send the link. I am able to send invites and able to successfully launch the app by clicking the dynamiclinks. Both the dynamically and manually created ones.

```
IDictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        values.Add("utm_campaign", "Health");
         values.Add("utm_medium", "GoIbibo");
         values.Add("ad", "1");
         values.Add("credit", "50");
         values.Add("utm_source", "Yahoo");
         values.Add("afl", "https://www.facebook.com");

        var intentbuidl = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder(MainActivity.mainActivity.GetString(Resource.String.invitation_title))
                         .SetMessage(MainActivity.mainActivity.GetString(Resource.String.invitation_message))
                         .SetDeepLink(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(MainActivity.mainActivity.GetString(Resource.String.invitation_deep_link)))
                         .SetAdditionalReferralParameters(values)
                         .Build();

        MainActivity.mainActivity.StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intentbuidl, "Install"),0);
```

Generated link: https://aku4q.app.goo.gl/i/619426442529-4a4105fd-33ea-4b0f-bf07-6f4063eef8f8

So my question is, when do invitees open the app using this link? Can we be able to get these additional parameters which I have set using IDictionary from the above generated link?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, no. This is one of the limitations of Firebase deep linking — you can't pass custom parameters and need to use the URL string for everything.

You could check out [Branch.io](https://branch.io/how-branch-links-work/) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) for an alternative approach that *does* allow custom parameters.